# Are Reactor operators like flatMap() that runs on same main thread any more efficient than regular blocking code?

Tags: project-reactor, flatmap

I understand that a lot of reactor operators like flatMap() run on the same thread on which the onNext method was invoked. What I am trying to understand is if such a method is any more efficient/performant non-blocking than a regular blocking call in say a for loop. Sorry if it's a noob question but I can't seem to grasp it. Is the power of reactive realized only when we use Schedulers that jump threads (e.g. Schedulers.parallel()) and so on?

e.g. if I had a function like the following

```
List<Integer> integers = Arrays.asList(5,6,7,8,9,10);
    Flux.fromIterable(integers)
            .flatMap(this::makeAReactiveMethodCall)
            .subscribe(r -> log.info(Thread.currentThread().getName()));
```

Logs look something like this - notice all the threads are the same "main" one.

```
01:25:40.641 INFO ReactiveTest - main
01:25:40.642 INFO ReactiveTest - main
01:25:40.642 INFO ReactiveTest - main
01:25:40.642 INFO ReactiveTest - main
01:25:40.642 INFO ReactiveTest - main
01:25:40.642 INFO ReactiveTest - main
```

All invocations happen on the same main thread. How is this code more efficient than making all the call in a for loop with blocking semantics? Say the following code?

```
integers.forEach(i -> this.makeAReactiveMethodCall(i).block());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming each `makeAReactiveMethodCall` does some I/O and takes 1 second to complete. Using the `flatMap` operator your calls will be made asynchronously. This means that the main thread will make all 6 calls without waiting for the I/O operation to complete(non-blocking), instead, it will process some other work and will be notified when a call is completed. In the case of `WebClient` and Project Reactor, this is achieved by using the Netty event loop to queue/dispatch/process events.

In the traditional, blocking way(eg. `RestTemplate`), it would take 6 seconds to make all 6 calls synchronously. Of course, you could use `ExecutorService` API to make it asynchronously, but in that case, you would need 6 threads because calls would be blocking. One of the advantages of the reactive model is that number of threads is limited, thus, resources are not wasted in multiple thread creation.

Comment: Thanks. So even wothout requiring additional threads the main thread can make 6 calls parallely? I suppose this is what I am not able to grasp. How is that possible, is there some other thread listening for the responses toncome from those 6 calls? Who spawns that thread?

Comment: @abhishekmishra I've updated the first paragraph.

Comment: So Project reactor always brings in netty? I guess I can check that myself. Wonder why this part is not made obvious in the documentation that there is some other worker which does the job of house keeping - the event loop.

Comment: With Spring WebFlux it's possible to switch to another embedded container such as Tomcat and its asynchronous Servlet 3.1 API but `spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty` is required to use the `WebClient`. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.5.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-embedded-web-servers.html

Comment: Yeah. So I what I understand is that any library that is facilitating making a reactive call out into another system will bring the dependency that includes the EventLoop implementation. In the case you suggested if we were to make an API call in a reactive fashion, we can use Spring WebFlux that'll bring in netty that provides the EventLoop implementation. Is that correct? This way just by doing a `flatMap()` we don't bring in the EventLoop but when an actual reactive call is made out of the system the EventLoop comes into picture.

Answer (score 1):

it's not if `makeReactiveMethodCall()` is doing CPU-bound work, or if it is not really reactive at all but a blocking call in disguise.

it's more efficient the moment `makeReactiveMethodCall` introduces some latency, eg. by performing I/O in a reactive manner.

there is also a tradeoff in composition and using a unified abstraction for your various processing steps that you might want to consider.

but if you're after pure throughput of CPU-bound code, then by all means use a good old loop.

Comment: Thanks. I understand the benefits of composition and unified abstraction for the processing steps. What I do not get is how is it more efficient when the method `makeReactiveMethodCall` is performing I/O in a reactive manner when my underlying reactive pipeline is only working with one main thread?